# unit of tx.gasprice and block.basefee

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price, fees, wei

I'm querying `tx.gasprice` and `block.basefee` on a mainnet fork pinned to block 15823986 -kind of recent one at the time of writing- and I'm getting `1991927019` and `991927019` respectively.

If these values are denominated in `wei`, when I convert them to `gwei` (aka dividing between 10 ** 9), I get `1.991927019` for the gasprice and `0.991927019` for the basefee, which doesn't make sense.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

On a fork, one tx equals one mined/validated block, so whatever computation you do before logging in gasprice and/or basefee might affect these two values at the moment of querying them.